# Under MonoTouch.NUnitLite when using Xamarin, "Run All" causes System.Reflection.TargetException

Tags: xamarin, nunit

I have created an iOS unit test project.

When I run my `[TextFixture]`s individually, everything is fine, all my tests pass.

If I choose `Run All` however, one `[TestFixture]` will pass but the others will fail with the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object of type 'MyNamespace.Tests.iOS.Tests.TestBar' doesn't match target type 'MyNamespace.Tests.iOS.Tests.TestFoo' 

TearDown : System.Reflection.TargetException : Object of type 'MyNamespace.Tests.iOS.Tests.TestBar' doesn't match target type 'MyNamespace.Tests.iOS.Tests.TestFoo'
```

It's always in the same pattern too. In the case above `MyNamespace.Tests.iOS.TestFoo` was run first and then any suite that tries to run next will generate those errors with the associated `[TestFixture]`.

**WORKING**

If I drill down to one of the `[TestFixtures]`s that failing in the simulator and run one test, then scroll to `Run All` for just that suite it's fine.

**FAILING**

If I get that error and drill down to one of the `[TestFixture]`s that failing in the simulator, then scroll to `Run All` for just that suite it fails.

So it seems the act of running **one** test in a suite must reset something but I don't know what.

It seems similar to this issue:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=18655

I do have async tests in play.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

... **LATER** ...

Digging further, I just tried upgrading to NUnit 3.6.1 and The corresponding runner:

https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin

And I don't get the errors, so it seems it's just a bug with the older version of NUnitLite?

Comment: Glad NUnit 3.x works for you. We're actively updating it, but we haven't seen any updates to the version released by Xamarin for years. I would recommend sticking with the NUnit 3.6.1 version rather than an old port. If you have any problems or suggestions, please reach out to us through the issues on GitHub.

Comment: Sweet updating to NUnit 3.x worked for me